# How to config Grape API time zone per request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

I want to manage multi time zone, in my Grape API, is there a way to add around filter to set the current user's time zone? like this in Rails

around_filter :set_time_zone

```
    def set_time_zone
      old_time_zone = Time.zone
      Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if logged_in?
      yield
    ensure
      Time.zone = old_time_zone
    end
```